# Service Protection Program keeps re-scheduling

Tags: windows, windows-10, services, scheduled-tasks

Something keeps re-scheduling SPP, asking for my windows activation key. SPP then performs it's usual procedure, checks my key, and accepts it. Then the (thing) wants to know again! It's a snowball effect.

I first saw it when I was monitoring my CPU usage and saw spikes. CPP was causing spikes, using up to 40% of my cpu then disappearing only to re-appear again.

I checked the Event Viewer. Under Programs, I see thousands of the same task going on... And on. When I click on a task, under 'Reason:' it says "Successfully scheduled Software Protection service for re-start at 2017-06-17T10:23:41Z. Reason: RulesEngine." what could RulesEngine be?

This is worrying as I assume CPP checks activation upon boot.

I have the event logs if needed. I did my best to find out what's going on, this is my first time troubleshooting a problem like this, and have no idea how to proceed.